# Negative bounds on variables in Linear Programming formulation

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am new to optimization theory and encountered the following problem:

I am reviewing a formulation for a network problem that is fed into a mathematical solver and I noticed that on the "bounds" section at the end there are arc flow constraints that are between a negative and positive value:

$$-80 \leq\text{line flow} \leq 80$$

How is this possible? I was expecting to just have two variables for each direction and bound them both on positive values. But I thought LP theory only allowed positive bounds on variables. Is my understanding incorrect?

Comment: The standard LP maximization problem has nonnegativity constraints. However, you can remove them, obtaining a non-standard LP.

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean that there are ways to solve a non-standard LP too ?

Comment: Yes. Do you have MATLAB? If so, use function `linprog`.

Comment: Ι mean from a mathematical point of view. Is it the case that it can be  converted and solved (e.g. simplex) or there are other methods that handle such special cases?

Comment: http://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~vazirani/algorithms/chap7.pdf